# Boy who can stop time by spreading his fingers

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for help identifying an urban fantasy type book (or series!) which I read in 1994.

The book takes place in modern day. The main things I remember from the story:

- a young boy learns that his family has a long history of being guardians or something
- he finds or receives one or more iron rings which he keeps on his belt. I don't remember the significance.
- there is a scene which occurs inside a barrow or underground cavern
- the boy is able to stop time by splaying or spreading te fingers on his hand

The novel was probably considered children's or YA.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like [The Dark is Rising](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Is_Rising_Sequence) series by Susan Cooper. The boy's name is Will. I remember him keeping the signs/symbols on his belt. They are rings with crosses quartering them, made of different materials. Finding these signs is part of his quest to fight the Dark. Names were also of some significance. It has been a long time since I've read these books but I'm almost certain it's what you are refering too. Will finds out he is the last of the Old Ones, and he does have some magic powers (though I don't recall if stopping time is one of them, this does sound familiar).

Comment: Awesome. This is it! Placed an order with Book Depository and am looking forward to reliving some of my childhood reads. Thanks!